# ¿Cuál es la manera más sencilla de inicializar un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
package menu;

import java.util.List;

public class Menu
{
   private String titulo;
   private List<String> opciones;

   public Menu(String titulo, List<String> opciones)
   {
       this.titulo = titulo;
       this.opciones = opciones;
   }

   public void mostrar()
   {
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println(titulo);    

       for (int i = 0; i < opciones.size(); i++)
       {
           System.out.println(i + 1 + ". " + opciones.get(i));
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Y en el método `main` he creado dos variables como se puede apreciar a continuación:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import menu.Menu;

public class Principal
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    String tituloMenu = "Menú Principal";
    List<String> opcionesMenu = Arrays.asList("Jugar", "Ver instrucciones", "Salir");
   //resto del código
  }
}
```

Mi problema radica en que estoy buscando una manera más sencilla de inicializar la variable `opcionesMenu`. La forma en que inicializo dicha variable la obtuvé investigando en SO, sin embargo no he podido concluir si se puede inicializar un `ArrayList` al estilo C#:

```
var opcionesMenu = new List<string> { "Jugar", "Ver instrucciones", "Salir" };
```

El otro problema radica en que no comprendo muy bien como funciona la inicialización del `ArrayList` que pongo en el código anterior. Básicamente tengo dos preguntas: ¿por qué es necesario usar `Arrays`? y ¿qué significa exactamente hacer uso del método `asList`?

Gracias de antemano por posibles comentarios y/o respuestas.

Comment: En esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288158/9621052) de Stack Overflow te dan diferentes métodos según la versión de tu JDK

Comment: @CryogenicNeo ya revisé ese enlace. De ahí obtuve la inicialización que pongo en mi código. Estoy buscando algo más sencillo, pero tal parece que no es posible. En fin, también tengo dudas sobre como funciona la inicialización que puse como ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Cual sería el estilo C#? ¿Puedes poner como se hace en ese lenguaje?

Comment: Debes entender la diferencia entre un `List`, `Array` y `ArrayList`. Se convierte de `Array` a `List`, para poder implementar los miembros de su interfaz (sus métodos). Pero al definir sus elementos en su declaración. Lo vuelve inmutable dependiendo si es tipo `ArrayList` o `List`. Puedes ver algunos ejemplos [En esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005083/5280677) y [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3676539/5280677).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes para entender cada una de las cuestiones que planteas.

> "...estoy buscando una manera más sencilla de inicializar la variable `opcionesMenu`..."

En java hay varias opciones de obtener una instancia de un objeto que implemente la interfaz `List` e insertarle datos "iniciales", el cual es el tipo de datos de tu variable `opcionesMenu`. Pero cada una depende de lo que quieras lograr, ya que cada una tiene sus características.

1 - Utilizando el operador `new`.

```
// Utilizo ArrayList, pero puede ser cualquier clase que implemente la intefaz List, por ejemplo LinkedList

// Variante 1
List<String> opcionesMenu = new ArrayList();
opcionesMenu.add("String 1");
opcionesMenu.add("String 2");
opcionesMenu.add("String 3");

// Variante 2
List<String> opcionesMenu = new ArrayList() {{
    add("String 1");
    add("String 2");
    add("String 3");
}};
```

Esta variante es la clásica o tradicional y también la más verbosa, cosa que a veces molesta un poco.

2 - A partir de un arreglo utilizando la clase `Arrays` (Método que utilizas).

```
// Variante 1. Arreglo externo
String[] arr = {"String 1", "String 2", "String 3"};
List<String> opcionesMenu = Arrays.asList(arr);

// Variante 2. Arreglo inline
List<String> opcionesMenu = Arrays.asList("String 1", "String 2", "String 3");
```

Esta opción puede ser útil si ya tienes un arreglo externo con los elementos que deseas insertar en la lista o si quieres ahorrarte un poco de código como las sucesivas llamadas al método `add()` del punto 1. Por otra parte, hay que tener bien claro y siempre presente, que la lista que se obtiene de este modo:

a. es de tamaño fijo, por lo que no es posible agregarle o quitarle elementos. Ambas operaciones lanzan una excepción del tipo `UnsupportedOperationException`.

b. si se utiliza la variante 1, la lista resultante sería una vista sobre el arreglo original, lo que quiere decir que si, por ejemplo, ordenamos la lista, el arreglo será ordenado de igual modo.

3 - Utilizando los métodos de factoría de la interfaz `List` (a partir de Java 9). Estos métodos también los encontramos en las interfaces `Set` y `Map`

```
// Variante 1
String[] arr = {"String 1", "String 2", "String 3"};
List<String> opcionesMenu = List.of(arr);

// Variante 2 (esta variante fue la que dió origen a la implementación de este método `of`)
List<String> opcionesMenu = List.of("String 1", "String 2", "String 3");
```

Esta opción nos permite crear de modo muy poco verboso una lista. Es muy parecido a si utilizamos la clase `Arrays`, pero es más comprensible de entender que lo que estamos creando es una lista si lo hacemos desde la interfaz `List`, en vez de utilizar la clase `Arrays`, que tiende a asociarse más a el trabajo con arreglos. Adicionalmente hay que saber que la lista que obtenemos será inmutable por lo que al igual que en el punto 2, no le podremos agregar o quitar elementos, pero a diferencia de dicho punto, tampoco podremos realizar operaciones como ordenamientos sobre ella. Con lo cual solo podremos realizar consultas sobre ella (obtener el elemento en una posición, recorrerla, etc).

> ¿por qué es necesario usar `Arrays`? y ¿qué significa exactamente hacer uso del método `asList`?

El uso de la clase `Arrays` no es obligatorio. Lo que ocurre es que antes de la llagada de los métodos de factoría para colecciones con Java 9, la opción menos verbosa que teníamos para obtener una lista a partir de un conjunto finito de elementos predefinidos, era el uso del método `asList` de dicha clase. En el punto 2 anterior te explico el uso de este método y sus características.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

No es necesario usar la clase Arrays. Puedes usar una lista, por ejemplo la clase ArrayList.

La forma tradicional de alimentarla sería:

```
ArrayList<String> opciones = new ArrayList();
opciones.add("Jugar");
opciones.add("Ver instrucciones");
opciones.add("Salir");
```

Te paso la liga de esa clase:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

También puedes usar un arreglo en sí y evitar la lista:

```
String[] opciones = new String[] {"Jugar", "Ver instrucciones", "Salir"};
```

No sé si eso sea sencillo para ti.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero hacer uso del método `add` no me convence ya que estoy buscando algo más "one-liner". No puedo usar arreglos porque necesito una estructura dinámica.

Comment: No hay manera de crear/inicializar un `ArrayList` de un modo más "one-liner".